# AttributeError: type object 'Game' has no attribute 'running'

Tags: python

I am confused about what to do. The type 'Game' has no attribute 'running'. I am a beginner at coding.

Below is my code snippets:-

from game import Game

```
while Game.running:
    Game.playing = True
    Game.game_loop()

(In second window)
import pygame

class Game():
```

Any help is appreciated !!!

Comment: please try and avoid posting images of your code and errors. Instead directly copy and paste the text in your question.

Comment: You need to create a instance of Game using `Game()`, and then call `running` and `playing` using this instance.

Comment: Ok. I will take that into note @BuddyBob

Comment: What is an instance @enzo ?

Comment: @Fishwikk you can edit the question to add the code.

Answer (score 0):

As the method `running` of class Game doesn't seem to be a classmethod, you can't directly call it using the class name. Either define the method `running` as classmethod by adding `@classmethod` on top of the method or create an instance of Game and then call the method using it.

But defining method `running` as @classmethod, you might have to tweak code a bit as per your requirements, so my suggestion is to create an instance and call the function using it.

Please refer the below link if you want to explore more on class methods:

[pythons-classmethod-and-staticmethod-explaine](https://stackabuse.com/pythons-classmethod-and-staticmethod-explained/)

[classmethod-in-python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/classmethod-in-python/)

### Edit

Example to create a use class instance in Python:

As your class `Game` **init** function doesn't accept any parameters, so you can directly create a game instance as below:

```
game = Game()
while game.running():
    # write all the code below using the same instance "game"
```

Comment: How do I make an instance of Game?

Comment: game = Game() , you can use `game` variable then

Comment: Let me edit the answer and give an example for the same

Comment: I have made an instance now it is saying NameError: name 'Game' is not defined.                             g = Game()

from game import Game

while g.running:
 g.playing = True
 g.game_loop()

Comment: The `g = Game()` line must come below the `from game import Game` line.

Comment: It's an import issue then, in which package is the Game.py file present

Comment: this is the new code and it is saying there is a unexpected indent                          while game.running():
 while game.running:
  game.playing = True
   game.game_loop()

Comment: @enzo, he removed the code snippets, I have seen it. It's there actually. He must be doing mistake while importing

Comment: @Fishwikk, inside which file is Game.py file present ? is the folder name `game`

Comment: here is the path: C:\Users\****\OneDrive\Desktop\game code\game.py

Comment: and the file where you are importing Game, is it in the same folder?

Comment: Try using any online indentation platform to indent your code properly. For example, use this :- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_python_formatter.htm

Comment: it is two separate python files but when I open sublime text, they are both open in windows

Comment: I have downloaded a file of the newly indented code and I am now going to try it